# How to verify transactions on ethereum blockchain?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, contract-deployment

I have a smart contract deployed in which there is a variable **A** whose value is updated through a public function **fun_update()**. I want to get all the addresses which updated that variable **A** through the function **fun_update()**.
How to do it without storing those addresses?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an event with the address and the recover the generated events.

```
event A_updated(address indexed updater);

function fun_update(uint newA) public {
    A = newA;
    emit A_updated(msg.sender);
}
```

Comment: I need to this for many functions like update, delete and others. And these functions will be called often. So is it good to do this for all?
It will take a lot of space and gas to store them as logs of events. Isn't it?

Comment: @Ritikkumar It is not free, you have to pay something but it is cheaper than using storage. For example LOG4 opcode is 1875 gas.

Comment: Ok Thanks I got it what you said. One last doubt if it's take less gas to store data in logs than in the storage. Still why storage is preferred to store most of the data in the blockchain?

Comment: @Ritikkumar There are several reasons: 1/ they cannot be accessed from a contract, 2/ they cannot be deleted and/or modified. Depending on the problem you may use one of them or both.

Comment: yup, makes sense. Thanks a lot for your valuable inputs.

Comment: can we do the above thing by directly going through all the transactions and finding those transactions which called this function?

Comment: It works if you do not use internal transactions. You need check the transaction `to` field is the contract, the first 4 bytes from the data match the function signature and make sure transaction was successful by checking the transaction's receipt. For internal transactions is more complicated you need a client that support transaction tracing.

Comment: 1) What do you mean by a client to support transaction tracing for internal transactions ? 
2) Also, Can I verify a external transaction t1 even if that transaction calls a internal transaction t2 using this method. I mean just to verify t1 not t2.
3) Also, It would be really helpful if you could provide some references or libraries for doing it for external transactions.

Comment: 1/ For example you need geth in archive mode to trace transactions. 2/ I don't understand the question. 3/ I don't know any library that does that, most people use events, they just work.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. Sorry for the 2), I misunderstood something. Now it's clear.